# Does the Android Webview support CSS3 WebKit Animations?

Tags: android, html, mobile, css

Does The WebView Control on Android OS support hardware accelerated css3 animations? And all the webkit css (for example: -webkit-transition bla bla) that I have that work on Safari Mobile do they work the same on android?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, according to [this page](http://caniuse.com/transforms3d)..
It supports starting from version 3.0 til last, beloved Jelly Bean ;)

On the other side developers experienced not super successful results. Quote from [here](http://daneden.me/2011/12/putting-up-with-androids-bullshit/):

> CSS animations are supported by Android devices — but only if a single
>   property is changed. As soon as you try to animate more than one
>   property at once, the entire element disappears. In non-native Android
>   browsers, the element will be visible for the duration of the
>   animation, but will hide immediately after it’s finished.

and update from the same source:

> ..it turns out Android 4.0 actually addresses this issue. Still, we need
>   to urge the authors of these resources to explicitly mention that full
>   support isn’t available in previous versions of Android..

So final answer 4.0+ version support it in a good way..

***UPDATE:*** From KitKat WebView is powered by Chromium (same engine as in Chrome browser) so from this Android version advanced HTML5 and CSS features should be fully supported.. More about this [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview)

Hope u find it useful.. ;)

Comment: Your answer is about Browser application, but the question is about WebView control. I tested a CSS rotation animation (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6410923/65899) inside a WebView, and it worked only on the latest 4.4 KitKat.

Comment: Thanks. Android WebView in KitKat is powered by Chromium engine, before it was powered by WebKit (basically same as old default browser..) so I updated the answer

Comment: My fault: I was trying to animate `:before` pseudo-element, and WebView had a bug until KitKat (probably this one https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92591). Except this, your answer is absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

If you want webkit transitions to be animated hardware accelerated in an Android Webview you'll need to enable hardware acceleration in the manifest file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >

    ...

    <application ... android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It's not perfect, but it improves the rendering a lot.