# *-transform: rotate works in Firefox but not chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

CSS looks as follows:

```
.rotate
{
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.rotate:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1); 
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1); 
}
```

Hovering over a `<span class="rotate">` will rotate the element in Firefox but not chrome.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BuHGQ/ (hover over the arrow)

What can be done so that it works in Chrome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
.rotate { display: inline-block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7nfD/1/

Comment: @dukevin it can probably be fixed with [-*-transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform-origin) or by giving it equal height and width.

Comment: Even I checked. It seems to work if the element has `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. Quite some funny behavior.

Comment: This is dependent on the version of Chrome. Latest versions appear fine.